# How to make a responsive div/button/image over two divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm testing two frameworks (skeleton.css and crow.css) to make responsive grids, but I can't centralize and put a div over two columns.
There's two pics showing how it will look:
[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXGgu.png)
[Smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QsOO.png)
The actual html code with crow:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/crow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="crow">
    <div class="ws-5 box">
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="images/img.png">
    <div class="ws-5 box">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.css with crow:

```
.box {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 550px;
}
.crow {
  position: relative;
}
```

Html code with skeleton:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="six columns box">
    </div>
    <img class="img" src="images/img.png">
    <div class="six columns box">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.css with skeleton:

```
.box {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 420px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solution within the frameworks you're using, or are you open to a custom code solution?

Comment: supposing dimensions of image are 100px*100px you can try `.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px); top: calc (50% - 50px);
}` but you need to define dimensions for .crow

Comment: @Banzay, nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css `transform` property to achieve the positioning you want.

It works by setting the left of `.img` to 50%, and then `transform: translate(-50%)` offsets it by half of its width to the right again, perfectly centring the `.img`

I have done the 'skeleton' one for you, but the "crow" one will be identical:

```css
.box {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="six columns box">
  </div>
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <div class="six columns box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent too much time styling this and @Zze beat me to the punch. But yes, relative and absolute positioning plus `translate()` will definitely get the job done.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 2.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 360px;
  }
.left, .right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
.content {
  background: #84bde4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: #f1c25e;
  box-shadow: 0px 16px 26px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="centered"></div>
  <div class="left"><div class="content"></div></div>
  <div class="right"><div class="content"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry Jesse, yours is looking great though!

Comment: Haha, no worries!